# POST request gets 'cancelled' status

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to make a POST-request that makes an insert into a table in the database and returns the created ID. The request seems to be processed as a record is created in the database. The problem is that I'm not able to return the value to my frontend, and in the network tab I can see that the request has a status of (canceled).
My other requests are GET-requests that also interact with the database, and they all go through normally.
Backend is Express, frontend is React, and the database is MySQL.

I tried the following:
- Checked if the issue is related to CORS.
- Tried other ways than using Axios.
- Tried to make the request directly with curl, this actually worked.

Express:

```
router.post('/search', function (req, res) {
    pool.query("INSERT INTO Searches(status)  VALUES('Started')"
        , function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("return result");
            console.log("insertId: " + result.insertId);
            let insertId = result.insertId;
            res.json(insertId);
            console.log("end of insert");
});
```

React:

```js
    handleSubmit() {
        console.log("handleSubmit");

        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/search', {test: "test"})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data)
            });
    }
```

I do see the insertId in the console log of my backend, but I don't get the value back in my frontend.

In the network tab I see there is first an OPTION request made (with status 204) and afterwards the POST request, which gets the status (canceled)

I have no idea why the request is canceled and I can't get the value back in React. Any idea on how I can solve this?

Comment: pass event and `handleSubmit(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }` 204 is probably because of that

Comment: That solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: @1565986223 your comment solved my issue. Thanks!!